# OpenGL Drawing to multiple textures

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to draw a scene's data to multiple textures. The textures hold the diffuse, normal, and position in color form. When the scene is rendered only one of the textures is drawn to. The gl_FragData[0] ends up in the texture with attachment GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2. If I switch gl_FragData[0] to diffuse, normal. or position the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 texture has the data correct so I know the data is correct in the shader but the first two textures end up blank.

```
int fbo = glGenFramebuffer();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
addTextureAttachment(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
addTextureAttachment(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
addTextureAttachment(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
Material.unbindAllTextures();

public void addTextureAttachment(int attachment) {
    int id = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer)null);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, attachment, GL_TEXTURE_2D, id, 0);
    textures.add(new Texture(id, width, height));
}
```

I call this before rendering

```
public void bindAsRenderTarget() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glDrawBuffers(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glDrawBuffers(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    glDrawBuffers(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
}
```

Comment: There's a section on the MRT rendering: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-frame-buffer-object-201-r2333

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. when I was calling glDrawBuffers 3 times I just needed to call a different glDrawBuffers that takes in a ByteBuffer containing the int GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT 0, 1, and 2 like this:

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(3 * 4);
    buffer.putInt(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    buffer.putInt(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    buffer.putInt(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
    buffer.flip();

    glDrawBuffers(3, buffer);
```